# MacBook Air (A1466) logic board part number

Tags: logicboard

Any idea what the part number is for this MacBook Air (A1466) logic board, or where I can find it printed on the board?

[image: MacBook Air (A1466) logic board]

It has no `xxx-xxxx-x` number on it and the serial number returns a different board type. I'd like to find out the actual part number so that I can replace the board.

The box says i5 (1.3 GHz) 4 GB, year 2013. I've given my serial number to three suppliers who've all sent me a different logic board. Something is amiss somewhere between the original config and the board now. So if I can just match this board, it would be great.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of logic boards that correspond to the A1466 model of the Apple MacBook Air 13", *some of which* I have listed below<sup>1</sup>, but I have highlighted the one for the year that you specified:

- 820-3209-A 661-6632 1,8 GHz *2012*
- **820-3437-B 661-7476 1.3 GHz *2013***
- 820-3437-B 661-00062 (4GB) 1.4 GHz *2014*
- 820-3437-B 661-00063 (8GB) 1.4 GHz *2014*
- 820-00165-A 661-02391 (4GB) 1.6 GHz *2015* EMC=2925

---

<sup>1</sup> There may be some missing, especically w.r.t. the memory configuration

Answer (score 2):

The part number is normally in the area where the SSD would be; in this case, hidden under that white sticker.
I do not believe your board is 820-00165 because I'm comparing it to one of those right now. Although its general shape is the same, some of the components are laid out differently.

EDIT May 28 2022:
Here's a photo of the 820-00165 board that I have. It's build 653-0023.[image: MacBook Air logic board 820-00165]

Answer (score -2):

Logic board Macbook Air A1466 2015 13" i5 1.6GHz 8Gb RAM 820-00165